# Pyspark: How to check whether a file path with wild character exists in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I want to check whether a file exists in an **s3** path and then read it as a spark dataframe. The problem is I do not know the exact path of the file, so I have to use wild characters. For example, my path looks something like this:

```
path = 's3a://dir1/dir2/someHashString-2021-09-29-14-52-randomStuff.gz'
```

I have no way of knowing what `'someHashString'` or `'randomStuff'` is, so, I probably have to use wild characters like this

```
path = 's3a://dir1/dir2/*-2021-09-29-14-52-*'
```

I am trying the first solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589969/how-to-check-a-file-folder-is-present-using-pyspark-without-getting-exception) like this :

```
def path_exists(path):
    # spark is a SparkSession
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    fs = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(
         sc._jvm.java.net.URI.create("s3a://" + path.split("/")[2]),
         sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration(),
                                                     )
    return fs.exists(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path))

path_exists(path='s3a://dir1/dir2/*-2021-09-29-14-52-*')
```

But it returns `False` even such a path does exist. How to check if this file path exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileSystem method [`exists`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#exists-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) does not support wildcards in the file path to check existence.

You can instead use [`globStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) which supports special pattern matching characters like `*`. If it returns a non-empty list then the file exists else it does not exist:

```
def path_exists(path):
    hpath = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path)
    fs = hpath.getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())

    return len(fs.globStatus(hpath)) > 0


print(path_exists("s3a://dir1/dir2/*-2021-09-29-14-52-*"))
# True
```